# Is a data set a database like object or a class like object? How do I reference to existing dataSet data from a class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dataset

In `C#` app created using `Visual Studio 2019` I have created using IDE a `Data Set` to store data for period of an application session.

[image: Form1 IDE]
[image: Dataset in IDE]

Should I treat `Data Set` as a:

1. database like object that stores data somewhere in a memory to which I can access from anywhere in my project (e.g. data set does not have instances but rather is a "place" to store data),   or
2. like a class which has instances and therefore I have to pass a reference to such dataSet each time I want to use data stored in it?

If the (1) answer is true I wonder how should I access data in this `Data Set` from a class level?

Comment: if you have created it manually, then you have to pass reference to every class. usually it is done via constructor.

Comment: I have created it using Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: I mean code, would be better if you showed us some. Or screenshots of your IDE

Comment: Man DataSet is a class it is created to hold database table data in memory for manipulation, and its created objects has same scope as other variables have

Comment: Thanks that answers my question. I had a thought that maybe a data set is some kind of internal memory object that I can access anywhere in the app as I can do it with a database.

Comment: The dataset is a class object than can be referenced any place in the code if it is public.  The data in the class you need to use the instance of the class in other places in the code and also need to be in a public location.

Answer (score 0):

Well my suggestion is that you look for some tutorials or demo projects. For me it was a good practice to look into code of projects and play around with it....

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6178/A-Practical-Guide-to-NET-DataTables-DataSets-and-D

As example.

When I learned the usage of DataGridView and data binding I started with xml files as "database". This was a good start to get into it and see how serialization works.